# How to save pairs of data into an one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have XML file where I have name of currency and rate. I want to save those currencies and rate as pairs into an array, but it doesnt work, when I echo the array with foreach only last one appears.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
$array=array();
foreach ($xml->children() as $cubeMain) {
    foreach ($cubeMain->children() as $cubeTime) {
        echo "Kursid seisuga: " . $cubeTime['time'];
        foreach ($cubeTime->children() as $cubeCurr) {
            $currency=$cubeCurr['currency'];
            $rate=$cubeCurr['rate'];
            $array = array((string)$currency => $rate);
            echo $currency . "&nbsp;" . $rate . "<br />";
        }
    }
}

foreach ($array as $currency => $rate){
    echo "$currency: $rate\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: *(sidenote)* there is a PEAR package for that at http://pear.php.net/package/Services_ExchangeRates

Comment: I think it's littlebit overkill for such small thing, I don't need yo convert:) But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to have several currency + rate couples, you'll want an array that contains sub-items, each one being made of currency + rate.

Typically, you'll first initialize your array :

```
$array = array();
```

Then, for each currency, you'll add an item into that array :

```
$array[] = array((string)$currency => $rate);
```

With that, you'll have a long list, but not indexed by currency -- which might not be that useful.

You'll probably, instead, prefer going with this second solution :

```
$array[(string)$currency] = $rate;
```

With that, **your array will have the currency as key** -- which make it much easier to find your data back, later.

Going with the second solution, your array is indexed by currency.

Which means you can find the rate for a specific currency this way :

```
echo $array['EUR'];  // if EUR is an exinsting currency
```

And loop over all data like this :

```
foreach ($array as $currency => $rate) {
    echo "$currency : $rate <br />";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$array[(string)$currency] = $rate;
```

instead of

```
$array = array((string)$currency => $rate);
```